# respectful owners ? Is that right?

Tags: errors

I am reading on many many websites or videos something like:

> "All rights goes to their respectful owners"
>   "Jack and other characters mention are property of Dreamworks and respectful owners"
>   "All characters are copyright to their respectful owners"
>   "All Photos belong to their respectful owners and are being used..."

I am puzzled. Should it not be "respective owners" ?

Well I am sure there should be owners who "show respect", but I am suspecting they are just misspelling a word in this context. Is that wrong ?

Comment: It should be *respective*. Are these websites (or the T&Cs thereof) written by people who don't speak very good English and/or copied from poor sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite right, it should be *respective*, have a look at the definitions for [respective](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/respective) and [respectful](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/respectful):

> re·spec·tive 
>   adj. 
> Relating to two or more persons or things regarded
>   individually; particular: successful in their respective fields.

and

> re·spect·ful 
>  adj. 
>  Showing or marked by proper respect.